# What is the right way to give Flatpak access to system binaries?

Tags: php, binary, atom-editor, sandbox, flatpak

I'm using the flatpak version of Atom. A lot of my extentions require paths to executable binaries such as the `php` binary for code completion.

Now Flatpak blacklists the `/usr` directory, do when I pass the `/usr/bin/php` directory it doesn't find the proper binary even if the binary is installed and it's directory is added to the `PATH` environment variable of the flatpak.

So what is the correct way to do it? I've also stumbled upon flatpak versions of the binaries themselves as extentions of the `org.freedesktop.Sdk` package, but if I'm to use those, how do I pass them to an Atom extention that requires a path to an executable?

Addendum: I recognise that there are workarounds such as not using Flatpak Atom and using the deb package instead, or using a different IDE flatpak that has the required binaries provided, but I'm interested in a solution to this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

By default the answer is no.. I saw your question went unanswered, so please try this. While this is for java, my hope is that you can try PHP... hope it helps you

However you can specify which ones you want..

#### Option 1:

add `--filesystem=host` option and then access them in the sandbox under `/run/host`.*

---

#### Option 2:

###### With Java 16 (1.16+) and later, & `enable the custom Java path option`

> right click on the instance you wish to use Java 16 for `> Click "Manage" > Enable "Custom Java Path" > And map the path to /app/jre/bin/java`